# Views Navigation Using Swipe Gesture

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

How can I switch views vertically using swipe gestures ?

Comment: Do you know how to do the same with android?

Comment: This might be the thing you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17540632/4757258

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found my answer. I am posting the code for your reference. Thanks :-)

in `viewDidLoad`

```
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedScreendown:)] autorelease];
  swipeGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
  swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
  [m_pImageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
```

Now

```
- (void)swipedScreendown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) swipeGesture {
  m_pViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
  CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
  transition.duration = 0.75;
  transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
  transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
  transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
  transition.delegate = self;
  [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
  [self.view addSubview:PadViewController.view];
}
```

If you need some more clarification please post here.

Comment: "How can i implement up and down swaping ?"

Answer (score 16):

Implement this (didload)

```
//........towards right Gesture recogniser for swiping.....//
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[urView addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
[rightRecognizer release];

//........towards left Gesture recogniser for swiping.....//
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[urView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
[leftRecognizer release];
```

Then This:

```
- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer 
{
//Do moving
}

- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer 
{
// do moving
}
```

Comment: Thanks rptwsthi. Can you please tell me in "do moving" what should I do ? Just loading of a viewController is fine ?

Comment: Sorry for being late, Yes, you can load, controller or add sub view, but i don't have any clue that how will you animate that.. :I

Comment: @rptwsthi This code was absolutely perfect!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @cardmagik at your service. :)

Comment: This work but the navigation is very quick. Anyway to slow it down or to work like Apple's (when in settings)

Comment: For that you will probably have to work with pan gesture recogniser!!

Answer (score 5):

Certainly! Just set your viewController to be the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and declare `UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRecognizer;` (also retain and synthesize). Then, in the implementation, set up the recognizers with

```
    UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    // RIGHT SWIPE
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                           action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
    // LEFT SWIPE
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    self.swipeLeftRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];
self.swipeLeftRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
    [recognizer release];
```

Then trigger the actions you want with the method

```
- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        // load a different viewController
    } else {
        // load an even different viewController
    }
}
```

What you do here is specific to your app. You can switch the tabBar selection, jump through a navigationController, present a different view modally, or just do a simple slide in transition.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response PengOne. One more thing - I want that view to be loaded like a scrolling screen. How can I do that ?

Comment: Animations... you can use a simple `UIViewAnimationTransition` or do a custom animation that's a little fancier. Google around for some nice examples.

Comment: I know I saw a post a while back on SO that gave instructions for getting a nice sliding transition similar to the default for navigationControllers, but I couldn't find it just now. I'm sure you will find it with a few choice search words. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Adding gestures in swift

```
func addSwipes() {
    // Left Swipe
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeLeft:")
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    // Right Swipe
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeRight:")
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
}

func swipeLeft(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
}

func swipeRight(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference PengOne, here is the code you referred to in your comment above. I saved it on my Mac because I thought it might be useful one day... :D

```
// Manual navigation push animation
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CurrentView"];
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"push-transition"];
```