# iOS - Open/Show view swiping down from navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiview, show

i would like to know if is possible open/show a new view swiping down ( or up ) from the navigation bar, just like the notification center view in iOS 5 ( it appear from status bar, and i think this isn't possible for normal apps, right? ).
Thanks :)

Comment: I found the solution, look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326816/views-navigation-using-swipe-gesture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Here's the code :

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(youSelector:)];
[swipeUp setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
[swipeUp setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
```