# Add UIGestureRecognizer to swipe left to right right to left my views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I have a UIStoryboard with different `UIViewControllers`, I would like to add another `UIViewController` (like a dashboard) that when the user swipe the ipad from left the dashboard will appear then when he swipe back the current view will be restored.

Is this possible? if yes any hint how to do it or any good tutorials for `UIGestureRecognizer`?

thank you.

Comment: Here is the answer to your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6326865/1965698

Comment: Thank you but i am looking for a way in storyboard approach,

Comment: can you tried my solution....

Answer (score 133):

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];
```

// SwipeRight

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swiperight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiperight:)];
swiperight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];
```

// Implement Gesture Methods

```
-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer 
{
       //Do what you want here
}

-(void)swiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer 
{
    //Do what you want here
}
```

Try this one.

Here is the swift version of above code.

Left Swipe

```
var swipeleft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipeleft:"))
swipeleft.direction = .left
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeleft)
```

Right Swipe

```
var swiperight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swiperight:"))
swiperight.direction = .right
view.addGestureRecognizer(swiperight)
```

Method implementation...

```
 @objc func swiperight(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        // Do what u want here
    }

 @objc func swipeleft(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        // Do what u want here
    }
```

Comment: I want to hold the ViewController in between the Dismissal How can i do that ??

Comment: didn't get your question exactly . You wanted to add animation while swiping ??

Comment: Sorry if i did not made myself clear ,
Here is  My question 
 "i want to add animation while swapping , like  in many other application when we drag to right on the screen ,Active screen fades away and when swipe is complete it closes, and the bottom controller become active .  now using the above code as soon as i start swipe it gets swiped instead of being smooth and slow ..

Comment: @ChaubeyJi Use UIPanGestureRecognizer instead of SwipeGesture.

Comment: How to use it in horizontal stackview by adding views runtime?

Comment: the moronic platform holder's documentation is so useless that after reading it so many times, I still can't figure out how to implement it and have to resort to googling and finally found the answer in stackoverflow

Comment: @Zennichimaro hope this answer helps.