# UITableViewCell subview not getting swipe gesture call back when swiping left

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have seen other questions on StackOverflow and have done the following:

> ```
> UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewDidSwipeLeft:)];
> swipeGestureLeft.delegate = self;
> [swipeGestureLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
> [self.mainView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureLeft];
>
> UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewDidSwipeRight:)];
> swipeGestureRight.delegate = self;
> [swipeGestureLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
> [self.mainView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRight];
> ```

I do not get `viewDidSwipeLeft`: calls

I added this in the tableView class too..

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Comment: Is mainview subview of the UITableViewCell ?

Comment: Are you set to scroll horizontally?  If so, the CV is probably stealing the gesture.

Comment: no horizonal scrolling. However, I am using the https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSDynamicsDrawerViewController

Comment: and the tableview is in the right pane

Comment: What `viewDidSwipeLeft:` method looks like?

Comment: Try this and check it... http://stackoverflow.com/a/17540632/3615320

Comment: seems like its an issue with the library:
https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSDynamicsDrawerViewController/issues/111