# Customizing UIView class with UIScrollview and UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I want to add three views in a UIViewController,

1. UIImageView
2. Scrollable Segment control ([HMSegmentedControl](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl))
3. UIViews (or) UITableviewCells

it looks like this,
[image]

When the whole view scrolls the segment control should pin at the top of the screen (like header in UITableview).

**My code**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

if ((long)scrollView.tag == 10) {

    // Main scrollview
    if (self.lastContentOffset >= scrollview.contentOffset.y) {
        NSLog(@"Down");
        if (scrollview.contentOffset.y < 158.0f) {
            [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollview.contentOffset.x, scrollview.contentOffset.y)];
            [matchInfoTable setScrollEnabled:NO];
            [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
        }
    } else if (self.lastContentOffset <= scrollview.contentOffset.y) {
        NSLog(@"Up");
        NSLog(@"%f",scrollview.contentOffset.y);
        if (scrollview.contentOffset.y > 138.0f) {
            [scrollview setScrollEnabled:NO];
            [matchInfoTable setScrollEnabled:YES];
        }

        if (scrollview.contentOffset.y >= 163.0f) {
            [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollview.contentOffset.x, 163.0f)];
            [scrollview setScrollEnabled:NO];
            [matchInfoTable setScrollEnabled:YES];
        }   
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset.y;

    NSLog(@"LastOffset :: %f",self.lastContentOffset);

} else if (scrollView.tag == MATCH_INFO) {
    // match info table

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) { // TOP
        [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollview.contentOffset.x, scrollview.contentOffset.y)];
        [matchInfoTable setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
    }
}
}
```

In this code when the segment control pin at the top. The below view is not scrolling continuously. I need to trigger its scrolling again.

All answers are appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I think better you should use **UIPageViewController** and put inside all tableviews, then you can detect swipes and change tabs.

Also you can use **UISwipeGestureRecognizer** and detect left and right swipes described in this post [left and right swipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540481/add-uigesturerecognizer-to-swipe-left-to-right-right-to-left-my-views)